# Count the leaves of an XML string with C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Is there a simple way to get the **number of all leaves** of an XML string (XML document is provided as a string) with C#?

Comment: You have to traverse the XML tree, and count all of the nodes that do not have descendants.  There might be a way to do it with a Linq  statement.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/1978692

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to find innermost nodes recursively from xml using c# or vb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978692/is-there-a-way-to-find-innermost-nodes-recursively-from-xml-using-c-sharp-or-vb)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var count = xDoc.Descendants().Where(n => !n.Elements().Any()).Count();
```

or as @sixlettervariables suggested

```
var count = xDoc.Descendants().Count(e => !e.HasElements);
```

Comment: Or simply `xDoc.Descendants().Count(e => !e.HasElements)`.

Comment: @sixlettervariables Nice. Updated the answer

Answer (score 4):

Here's how to do it with XPath (to borrow from helio):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("...");
int count = doc.SelectNodes("//*[not(*)]").Count;
```

- `//` Means to match all descendants
- `*` Means any XML element
- `[]` Indicates a condition
- `not(*)` Means that the current element has no child elements